# Obtain $L^p$ norm by using "Riesz Representation"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded with smooth boundary. Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ be given. Hence, we have 
$$
\int_\Omega|{\nabla u}|^2<\infty.
$$
Let $\nu\in \mathcal S^{N-1}$ be given. Here $\mathcal S^{N-1}$ denotes the $N$ dimensional unit sphere. We have 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u \cdot \nu|^pdx\leq \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^pdx<\infty
$$
by $|\nu|=1$. (Note $\nu$ is only a unit vector here, not a function)

My question 1: do we have 
$$
\sup_{\nu\in \mathcal S^{N-1}}\int_\Omega |\nabla u \cdot \nu|^pdx =? \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^pdx
$$
My question 2: can I replace 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^pdx
$$
by 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^pd\mu
$$
where $\mu$ is a positive finite Radon measure, and still have the same result as in question 1?

Thank you!

---

PS: I feel the Riesz Representation has sth to do about my questions... but I am not sure...

---

PPS: If my question 1 does not work. Would it be helpful to partition $\Omega$ into a countably many small pieces and do $\sup$ at each of them and sum up? i.e., will this work?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{\nu\in\mathcal S^{N-1}}\int_{\Omega_n}|\nabla u\cdot \nu|^p dx = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^pdx
$$
where $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Omega_n=\Omega$ and $\Omega_n$ is disjoint with each other.

Comment: Derivatives have nothing to do with this problem. You are asking whether, given a vector-valued function $v\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$, one has that $$\int |v(x)|^p\, dx \overset{?}{=} \sup_\nu \int |v(x)\cdot \nu|^p\, dx.$$ I suspect that the answer is negative.

Comment: What is true is $\sup_{|v|=1}\int |\nabla u \cdot v|^p\,dx \asymp \int |\nabla u|^p\,dx $.

Comment: @PhoemueX Can you give more information about that special symbol you are using?

Comment: $A \asymp B $ if $A \leq C_1 B $ and $B \leq C_2 A $ for certain absolute constants $C_1,C_2 >0$. In your case, these constants depend on $N,p $.

Comment: @PhoemueX I see. Do you have any reference for those constant $C_1$ and $C_2$? I wish to know what is the value of them and I may try to adjust it to suit my purpose. (I only consider the case $p=2$)

Comment: I came back to this question and noted that, probably, the other answer suits you much better than mine, so you should accept it instead. Moreover, that simple argument applies verbatim to any (positive) measure, not just to the Lebesgue's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments already revealed, the answer is negative. Consider the function
$$f(x, y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$$ 
on the square domain $\Omega=[0,1]\times [0,1]$. You have that 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla f(x, y)|^2\, dxdy= \frac23, $$
but if $\nu=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, then 
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla f(x, y)\cdot \nu|^2\, dxdy = \frac13 + \frac{\cos \theta\sin\theta}{2}, $$
whose maximum is $\frac13+\frac14$, strictly smaller than $\frac23$.

Comment: I agree sir. But would the partition be helpful?

Comment: Maybe. I recall having seen such tricks on papers in harmonic analysis, some time ago. Look for instance in the book by Stein, in the proof of the multidimensional Van der Corput. The author uses a partition trick to reduce the multidimensional problem to a one-dimensional one, which is more or less what you need, I suppose. The same trick is used [here](https://www.uam.es/departamentos/ciencias/matematicas/AFA/AFA2004/files/2005-pub/RV05-converg.pdf) in the proof of Theorem 3 - look for "so defining $U_j$ by ..." (BTW, I am no "sir"! I am just a wannabe mathematician :-) ).

Comment: @tankonetoone:  Also, forget about the reference I gave you. I don't think it is useful and I hope I did not confuse you too much.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @GiuseppeNegro, we do not get exact equality. But one can get "asymptotic equality" as follows:

As you noted yourself, we have
$$
\sup_{|v|=1} \int |\nabla f \cdot v|^2 dx \leq \int |\nabla f|^2 dx,
$$
simply by Cauchy Schwarz.

Conversely, by taking $v =e_i $ to be an element of the standard basis, we get
$$
\sup_{|v|=1} \dots \geq \int |\partial_i f|^2 dx
$$
for every $i \in \{1,\dots n\} $. Now, sum over $i $ to get
$$
\sup \dots \geq \frac {1}{n} \int |\nabla f|^2 dx. 
$$